# Форматирование локального времени в PHP

Tags: unixtimestamp, php

Добрый день.
Требуется сделать на сайте систему времени так, чтобы у каждого пользователя выводилось время его часового пояса.

Решил пойти таким путем : указал  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin');

т.е по UTC 0  Все время в базу заносится в секундах time() соответственно по нулевому мередиану.

Потом при выводе времени кидаю ее в самописную ф-ю которая с базы берет часовой пояс текущего пользователя и соотв. делает +х часов или -х часов

```
function return_time($sek,$gmt){
if($gmt>=0){$gmt=str_replace('+','',$gmt); $gmt=$gmt*3600; $itog = $sek+$gmt;}
if($gmt<0) {$gmt=str_replace('-','',$gmt); $gmt=$gmt*3600; $itog = $sek-$gmt;}
return $itog;
}
```

Но вот беда... Время почему-то сдвигается на +1 час.
т.е Для дублина/Лондона он показывает время на час большее чем оно есть на самом деле.
Для меня тоже...
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: в этом кусочке всё верно,но проверьте то ли значение $gmt приходит, ошибка скорей всего дальше при выводе либо форматировании даты.

Comment: Я проверяю вот так вот:
 Добавлен : <? echo date("H:i:s",time());?> / <?echo date("H:i:s",return_time(time(),$_SESSION['gmt']));?>

т.е вывожу текущую дату Лондона + дату со смещением...
И уже первая дата не верна.. Разница в час..

Comment: Решено.. На сервере все норм. комп учитывал летнее время, хотя оно и отключено

Answer (score 2):

очевидно, время на сервере указано со смещением в один час, т.е. time() возвращает на 1 час больше чем вам надо. А значит ошибка в

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin');
```

попробуйте

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Answer (score 1):

1 По Гринвичу это `UTC`, а не `Europe/Dublin`.

2 `timestamp` всегда хранит время по Гринвичу, не зависимо от временной зоны сервера.

3 Для форматирования локального времени применяются функции [**gmstrftime**](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.gmstrftime.php) и [**gmdate**](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.gmdate.php), которым совершенно безразлична временная зона севера.

4 Для форматирования локального времени каждого пользователя, лучше вместо временных зон использовать временное смещение в секундах, которое, в отличие от временной зоны, легко определяется через `JavaScript`, а затем записывается в куки и передаётся на сервер, откуда сервер, уже зная временное смещение пользователя, прибавляет его к исходному `timestamp` и отправляет пользователю отформатированное локальное время.

5 Подробнее про работу с временными зонами описано [**тут**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/578789/209154).

Answer (score -1):

Зачем столько кода, когда можно обойтись просто стандартной ф/е:

```
echo date ("H:m:s");
```

Для переменной:

```
$dated = date ("H:m:s");
```

Эта - ф-я показывает время что настроена в компьютере.

Comment: не на компьютере, а на сервере где установлен php, и для всех пользователей будет одинаково.