# Работа с часовыми поясами на сайте

Tags: php, javascript, время, unixtimestamp, timezone

Появилась на сайте необходимость выводить время относительно локального часового пояса каждого пользователя.
Дату на сервере храню в `unixtimestamp`.
Я сначала подумал хранить временную зону на сервере, вместе с профилем пользователя, при этом в первый раз определить её через `javascript` автоматически, а потом предоставить пользователю возможность её изменять.

Но, как оказалось, `javascript` не умеет определять `timezone` из ОС и в придачу вообще не умеет работать с временными зонами, а только со смещением.

Что бы это работало, нужно просить пользователя вручную указать текущую временную зону, без автоопределения, а для `ajax` вычислять смещение средствами PHP и передавать её в `javascript`.

Но всё это слишком накладно. Современный пользователь на столько ленивый и глупый, что он в принципе может не знать название своей временной зоны, и указывать её не верно, без подсказки автоопределения просить об этом пользователя накладно. С другой стороны, популярные соцсети и видеохостинги прекрасно справляются с этой задачей и при этом не просят пользователя указывать временную зону.

Вот вопрос, как мне не прося пользователя указывать его временную зону, выводить время средствами `PHP` и `JS`, в родной часовой зоне для каждого пользователя, и как, например, эту задачу решают вконтакт и ютуб?

Comment: Соцсети решают этот вопрос определяя регион пользователя по IP.

Comment: @YuS, а если я через tor, vpn или прокси, зайду не ужели они мне покажут это во времени относительно расположения оных?

Comment: @IlyaIndigo, чем вас не устраивает смещение, которое отдает js? Оно в секундах считается. Отнимайте его от unixtimestamp и получайте время юзера.

Comment: @Visman, тем, что смещение само смещение не постоянно, и хранть его в БД нет смысла. Смысл есть только вернуть `ajax`-ом это смещение а потом, на основании этого смещения отобразить пользователю, формируя страницу через `PHP`. Но мне на этапе формирования страницы в `PHP` уже нужно знать это смещение или временную зону. Или я чего-то не понимаю? В голову приходит только вывести время по-серверу, а потом при загрузки документа, произвести корректировку через `JS`, но это костылище. Я думаю должно быть более элегантное решение.

Comment: На этом сайте так и делается - через js идет пересчет.

Comment: Насколько я понял, это всё нужно только, чтобы выводить время средствами `php`? Я бы рекомендовал просто оставлять время пустым(скажем `<span class="time" data-timestamp="1487134181" data-format="H:i"></span>`), а после загрузки страницы заполнял его js, формируя из unixtimestamp.

Comment: @vp_arth А теперь представьте 2 ситуации. 1 - частично-описанная мною во 2-ом замечании, когда у клиента отключен JS... 2 При медленном соединении или сильной загрузки, во время загрузки и до момента её окончания, будут красоваться пустые даты.

Comment: `Красоваться пустые даты` - нарисуйте спиннер. `Отключен js` - ссзб, у меня большинство проектов на `angularjs`, мне не понять заботу об этих ребятах.

Comment: Посмотрите как [moment.js работает](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) (он показывает правильную временну́ю зону)

Comment: @jfs Благодарю за информацию!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решил задачу достаточно элегантно.**

Так как JS не умеет определять локальную временную зону, но умеет форматировать `unixTimeStamp` в локальное время, придётся забыть про передачу форматированной временной строки с сервера, и передавать клиенту `unixTimeStamp` для последующего форматирования в локальное время силами JS.
Что бы сделать заполнение данных локальным временем менее заметным для пользователя, а также код на сервере не изменять, вместе с `unixTimeStamp` на место локального времени всегда передаём время по Гринвичу.

**Порядок решения** таков.

**1** В PHP форматируем время всегда только по Гринвичу, используя `gmdate()`, а также назначаем класс `dateTime` элементу, содержимое (`innerHTML`) которого нужно будет форматировать.
В один из атрибутов этого элемента `data-date-time`, `data-date`, `data-time`, помещаем `unixTimeStamp` в зависимости от того, во что его нам нужно форматировать.

```
<p>Дата со временем: <span class="dateTime" data-date-time="<?=$date?>"><?=gmdate('d.m.Y (H:i)',$date)?></p>
<p>Дата: <span class="dateTime" data-date="<?=$date?>"><?=gmdate('d.m.Y',$date)?></p>
<p>Время: <span class="dateTime" data-time="<?=$date?>"><?=gmdate('H:i',$date)?></p>
```

**2** В числовом прототипе JS определяем удобные методы для форматирования времени и определяем удобную функцию `dateTime()`, которая после загрузки документа получит все элементы, нуждающиеся в форматировании и заменит их время/дату/дату со временем, в зависимости от того, в каком атрибут будет помещён `unixTimeStamp` с Гринвича на локальное время. Вызываем нашу функцию `dateTime()` после окончания загрузки документа.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
<!--
    'use strict'; 
    Number.prototype.time=function()
    {
        return new Date(this*1000).toLocaleString('uk',{'hour':'numeric','minute':'numeric'});
    }
    Number.prototype.date=function()
    {
        return new Date(this*1000).toLocaleString('uk',{'day':'numeric','month':'numeric','year':'numeric'});
    }
    Number.prototype.dateTime=function()
    {
        return this.date()+' ('+this.time()+')';
    }
    function dateTime()
    {
        let doc=document.getElementsByClassName('dateTime');
        for(let l=doc.length,i=0;l>i;++i)
            if(typeof doc[i].dataset.dateTime=='string')
                doc[i].innerHTML=parseInt(doc[i].dataset.dateTime).dateTime();
            else if(typeof doc[i].dataset.date=='string')
                doc[i].innerHTML=parseInt(doc[i].dataset.date).date();
            else if(typeof doc[i].dataset.time=='string')
                doc[i].innerHTML=parseInt(doc[i].dataset.time).time();
    }
    window.addEventListener('load',dateTime);
//-->
</script>
```